# Remove \def in enumerate

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm trying to produce a very clean latex code for an article submission using knitr. One of the guidelines is to not define new commands. However right now a simple markdown list uses it by default.

This minimal .Rmd

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
---

1. First

1. Second
```

Produces this .tex output

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\item
  First
\item
  Second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to not put the `\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.` line?

(I know I can write latex code right into the Rmd document, but it's very tedious and I rather deal with markdown as much as I can. )

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc has no built-in way of removing this. It could be argued that it ought not to be a problem, as the above `\def` only sets the value of an existing variable instead of defining a new command; but the journal might disagree.

The easiest way to get rid of this would be to manually post-process the output. I.e., use a tool like `sed` or the search-and-replace functionality of your favorite editor.

```
sed -i -e '/^\\def.*/d' your-article.latex
```

An automated, but complex approach would be to do list rendering via a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html). However, that seems like more trouble than it's worth in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to circumvent the issue by using `#.` instead of `1.`. I'm not entirely sure why, but

```
#. First

#. Second
```

Produces de desired output

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  First
\item
  Second
\end{enumerate}
```

Is not ideal, but good enough!